# Installing and setting up an IMAP server?

Tags: security, debian, imap

I want to set up an IMAP server on my vServer. I googled for some servers, and I've already found some like dovecot etc. I would like to know which one is the most secure one, and which one you recommend to install. Moreover, it would be great if there are any tutorials out there to set the IMAP server up.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are a number of tutorials out there specifically for Debian if you just look.  E.g., [this one](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/275).

Comment: Both [product and service recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and "Please find me a tutorial on how to do X" questions are generally poorly suited for this site -- Google is a far better resource for these things.  As Chida's answer mentioned, security is not a product - it's a commitment to properly configure and maintain your software once it's installed.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing as the "most secure" one. The most secure one is the one that you configure, update and maintain regularly and proactively.

Having said that, Courier-IMAP has been around for a while. Dovecot seems to be the modern one and is a recent active project.  It is designed from ground up to address features, security, performance and reliability.